# OpenCV image inpainting result not as expected, any other options?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have this photo that I want to remove the lines away. I used cv2's inpainting method but it somehow results in kind of distorted. My mask seems fine too. Are there any other types of removal if inpainting is not ideal for this type of photos?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fahOd.jpg)

[Inpainting output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I46sO.png)

Comment: OpenCV has those two *simple* inpainting methods. they don't use image patches, like you seem to expect.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I see. Are there any other options for the patches?